# Android: App works on all devices except Samsung. How to solve? FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2

Tags: android, android-asynctask, samsung-mobile

The application I'm building at the moment works on all devices except the once from Samsung. And the error is Android version independent.

Here is my error report when running the app on an Samsung galaxy or a Samsung tab 10.1:

```
11-02 10:04:49.748: I/System.out(11183): Wrong XML file structure: Unexpected token (position:TEXT File does not ex...@1:20 in java.io.StringReader@418eb450) 
11-02 10:04:49.748: W/dalvikvm(11183): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c511f8)
11-02 10:04:49.763: E/AndroidRuntime(11183): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
11-02 10:04:49.763: E/AndroidRuntime(11183): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-02 10:04:49.763: E/AndroidRuntime(11183):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
11-02 10:04:49.763: E/AndroidRuntime(11183):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
11-02 10:04:49.763: E/AndroidRuntime(11183):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
11-02 10:04:49.763: E/AndroidRuntime(11183):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
11-02 10:04:49.763: E/AndroidRuntime(11183):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-02 10:04:49.763: E/AndroidRuntime(11183):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-02 10:04:49.763: E/AndroidRuntime(11183):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-02 10:04:49.763: E/AndroidRuntime(11183):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-02 10:04:49.763: E/AndroidRuntime(11183): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 10:04:49.763: E/AndroidRuntime(11183):    at com.lgsvcacademy.lgrepairsupport.ErrorCodeList$GetDataTask.doInBackground(ErrorCodeList.java:167)
11-02 10:04:49.763: E/AndroidRuntime(11183):    at com.lgsvcacademy.lgrepairsupport.ErrorCodeList$GetDataTask.doInBackground(ErrorCodeList.java:1)
11-02 10:04:49.763: E/AndroidRuntime(11183):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
11-02 10:04:49.763: E/AndroidRuntime(11183):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-02 10:04:49.763: E/AndroidRuntime(11183):    ... 4 more
```

Added the code in ErrorCodeList around line 167:

```
String feedURL="...";
String xml = XMLfunctions.getXML(feedURL);
Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);

int numResults = 1;

if((numResults <= 0)){
   Toast.makeText(ErrorCodeList.this, "No results found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
   finish();
}      

/*Line 167>*/ NodeList troubles = doc.getElementsByTagName("trouble");
for (int i = 0; i < troubles.getLength(); i++) {
String troubleTypeAtt;

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

Element e = (Element)troubles.item(i);
troubleTypeAtt = e.getAttributes().getNamedItem("type").getNodeValue();
if((troubleTypeAtt.equals("error")) || (troubleTypeAtt.equals("notification"))) {
...
```

What could be the problem? My AsyncTask works perfectly on any other device. What is different on a samsung phone?

Comment: We can not answer this question without knowing what you are doing in  ErrorCodeList. Please post the code in the method that generates the NullPointer, should be somewhere around: ErrorCodeList.java Line 167

Comment: Share your Code for better Discussion

Comment: I have added my code as requested, sorry for my code being absent.

Comment: It looks that for some reason doc is null. Try to check via the debugger if doc is really null. If it is null the XMLfromString method returns null for some reason and you have to look for your error there.

Comment: But why does it do it only on a Samsung device?

Comment: Does your Samsung device have a different Android version than your other devices? It's more likely that the reason for the different behaviour is different OS versions than that it's a Samsung specific problem.

Comment: Btw. the first line of your logcat dump hints that there's something wrong with the XML that's parsed -- it is also quite obvious that doc must  be null in your line 167, so it seems that the XML is incorrect and therefor the parsing fails and returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I solved it. @Janusz a little bit of debugging did the trick. The problem was not in the XML structure nor in the fact that the error occurred on only Samsung devices. What happened was that my XML hyperlink listens to the language of the device and then gets the correct XML file. But during development I didn't had a certain language on the server yet happens to have the coincidence that all the Samsung devices I got from my colleagues had that particular language on them. doh! Never the less thanks for thinking with me!